# Using Elasticsearch REST API with Browser: how to do AND operation

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I want to know how can I search for 2 key:value pairs with the browser on localhost:9200

For Example: want to combine country=CAN AND brand=V

```
_source": {

    "country": "CAN",
    "brand": "V",
    "leadID": 10333,
    "datetime": 1442247315000

}
... and so on
```

I tried this uri with the "default_operator" set to AND:

```
http://localhost:9200/_search?default_operator=AND&q=country:CAN&q=brand:V
```

In the response I got country=CAN with brand=V, but I also got country=PRT with brand=V. So it did an OR operation instead of AND operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `http://localhost:9200/_search?default_operator=AND&q=country:CAN AND brand:V`

Your browser will translate it to `http://localhost:9200/_search?default_operator=AND&q=country:CAN%20AND%20brand:V`

meaning you combine the two conditions into one: `q=country:CAN AND brand:V`.